# Avoid line break before acronym

Tags: line-breaking, acronyms

I use the acronym package for acronyms. E.g., I would define a new acronym as `\newacro{CDN}{content delivery network}` and then use it by writing `\ac{CDN}`. The first occurrance of this prints: "content delivery network (CDN)"

Sometimes there is a line break before the abbreviation, e.g., after "network" and before "(CDN)". Is there any way to prevent line breaks here? I don't mind line breaks at other positions, e.g., between "content" and "delivery".

I know there are a lot of related questions, but none solves my problem.

Comment: Please post a MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `\@acf` which prints the acronym as `Full (Short)` is coded as

```
\newcommand*{\@acf}[1]{%
\ifAC@footnote
\acsfont{\AC@acs{#1}}%
\footnote{\AC@placelabel{#1}\AC@acl{#1}{}}%
\else
\acffont{%
\AC@placelabel{#1}\AC@acl{#1}%
\nolinebreak[3] %
\acfsfont{(\acsfont{\AC@acs{#1}})}%
}%
\fi
\ifAC@starred\else\AC@logged{#1}\fi}
```

The `\nolinebreak[3]` already discourages spacing but does not forbid it (see [What is the difference between \nobreak and \nolinebreak?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94217/106162)).  To forbid breaking, `\nolinebreak[4]` or simply `~` can be used instead in the definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@acf}[1]{%
\ifAC@footnote
\acsfont{\AC@acs{#1}}%
\footnote{\AC@placelabel{#1}\AC@acl{#1}{}}%
\else
\acffont{%
\AC@placelabel{#1}\AC@acl{#1}%
\nolinebreak[3] %
\acfsfont{(\acsfont{\AC@acs{#1}})}%
}%
\fi
\ifAC@starred\else\AC@logged{#1}\fi}
\makeatother

\newacro{PDF}{Portable Document Format}

\begin{document}
Foooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo \ac{PDF}
\end{document}
```

Or to follow [clemens' approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271496/106162) and do it a little less invasively

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@acf
  {\AC@acl{#1}\nolinebreak[3] \acfsfont{(\acsfont{\AC@acs{#1}})}} % search
  {\AC@acl{#1}\nolinebreak[4] \acfsfont{(\acsfont{\AC@acs{#1}})}} % replace
  {} % success
  {} % failure
\makeatother
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the error `Command \@acf already defined.`

Comment: The first code snippet is just the definition of `\@acf` from `acronym` use either the `\renewcommand` code from the full document or the `etoolbox` code instead (I'm pretty sure neither of them should yield an `already defined` error). If you copy the full document I have in the answer does that compile for you?